# Can I control 6-7 devices of 12v max (each) with Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, voltage, dc-motor, arduino-uno

I have to control following devices:

- 2 × Gear motors (each 12V, 200mA, **speed & direction**)
- 1 × Motor (12V , 1.2 A, **on / off**)
- 1 ×    Motor (3V, 110mA, **on / off**)
- 1 × dc pump (5V, 300mA, **on / off**)
- 2 × servo (5V, 100mA each, **speed, direction, angle**)
- Minor sensors.

I have [**L298 dual full-bridge driver ICS**](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/82/cc/3f/39/0a/29/4d/f0/CD00000240.pdf/files/CD00000240.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000240.pdf) rated at up to 40+ V and 4A per bridge.

Is it possible?
How much input voltage is required?
How can such high voltage be handled?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I have to control speeds of some of the motors as well. I have l298 drivers. I wanted to know if it could handle the high voltages and current. Please review the question.

Comment: *I wanted to know if it could handle the high voltages and current* So what does the datasheet of the L298 tell you?

Comment: I'll be quite frank: Looking at what you asked and the way you asked, I am afraid this project is beyond your current skills. You seem to have little knowledge of very basic electronics concepts like voltage, current and power. I don't think you know the difference between controlling a servo and a geared motor, let alone how to make a speed control. You would need to make various supplies. I would suggest you build up slowly, connect one motor at a time. Get it to work and only make a combined project in the end. Depending on your time and devotion, that can take from 4 months to a year.

Comment: you can control the 12V DC motor by using the L293D IC here is the link 
    https://www.electronicshub.org/dc-motor-control-arduino/       & here is the tutorial about how to handle servo using arduino  https://www.robotshop.com/community/tutorials/show/arduino-5-minute-tutorials-lesson-5-servo-motors   & for power supply you have to buy 12V 5A SMPS and then convert voltage level using voltage regulators like LM7812 , LM7805

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can - but you will invariably need some sort of control interface.

Added: You have now said that you have L298 full bridge drivers available. This makes an immense difference to the question and to answers. I have added brief mention below of how the l298 related to my prior answer. Essentially, most if not
all of the driver tasks could be handled by L298 drivers under Arduino control.

- [L298 / Arduino driver tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-the-L298-Motor-Driver-Module-Arduino-Tu/)
- [L298 & Arduino Tutorial video - 11 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kv-9mxVaVzE)
- [L298 & Arduino Tutorial video -  36 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyjo_ggEtVU)
- [Many many related web pages](https://www.google.com/search?q=i298+driver+arduino&tbm=isch&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiS1uL3rpXjAhV56nMBHfo-Ax8QsAR6BAgCEAE&biw=1440&bih=757)
- [And more ...](https://www.google.com/search?ei=ZtQaXfbTIdTe9QPysofgAQ&q=i298+driver+arduino&oq=i298+driver+arduino&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1262078.1265194..1265563...0.0..0.283.1679.0j4j4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i22i30j33i160j33i21.PC4eKhpGEco)

**_________________________**

---

You need to say whether you want

- just on/off control, or variable speed,
- and/or variable direction -
- and what degree of speed control accuracy you want.
- Also rate of change of speed, accuracy/resolution, braking control aspects etc.
- And are they brush type motors or "brushless". If brushless, do you have "RSCs" for them or expect the UNO to do that task to ... /

A full description of the task will get a far more useful answer.

A simple on/off control of permanent magnet brushed motors rated at under say 10A each can take as little as a MOSFET, diode and a resistor per motor.

A speed controlled brushless uni-directional motor may not take much more for "open loop" control. Add speed feedback and you need extra control oins and sensors.

Add bidirectional control and you get more complexity again.

Somewhere aling the way you run out of UNI I/O pins and start to need latches or multiplexers or ... .

For brushless DC motors you need more control electronics and may run into speed issues with masny motors - and it may mske sense to add some extra lowcost extra microcontrollers.

Tell us what you REALLY want and we'll tell you how to do it.

---

Added:

You are not helping yourself.
If you want good answers (which we can give you if we know enough) then **YOU** need to tell us what you do know IN YOUR QUESTION.

eg Gear motors

- draw about xx Amps at 12V.
- They are [on/off only | variable speed by varying voltage] and
- [monodirectional | need to be reversed by reversing voltage].
- etc.

WHAT website are the specs not given on?
If **YOU** are going to hope to control these you MUST know data re
current,
on off or variable,
direction etc.
per motor.
You MUST know these - or your task is undefined  and sounds like "I want to do something. How do I do it?"

Please, HELP US HELP YOU !!!!

---

**Added to address supplied information:**

> I have to control following devices:
>
> 2 X Gear motors (each 12V, 200mA, speed & direction)

L298 performas this task easily. See below for details.

Various possibilities.
Most conventional approach is an H bridge with PWM of two bottom legs for speed control.
An H bridge has 4 switches - left upper and lower, right upper and lower.
To move in one direction enable left upper and PWM right lower.
To move in other direction enable right upper and PWM left lower.
Upper drives can be complementary (hihgh-low or low-high so a single uC bit can set direction.  PWM can be switched only to relevant lower side with very little logic circuitry so one bit for PWM.

So each gear motor takes 2 IO bits so 4 bits total.

> 1 X Motor (12V , 1.2 A, on / off)

1 bit, turn FET on/off.

> 1 X Motor (3V, 110mA, on / off)

1 I/O bit.
Could use a 3V voltage regulator and enable with a FET.
If you have a 3V supply can power directly.
If you have 5V supply you can use a regulator - linear reg dissipation = V x I = (5V-3V) x 0.11A = 0.22W = easily handled by TO220 or SMD package with due heatsinking.
From 12V linear regulator = (12v-3V) x 0.11A =~ 1 Watt.
OK with TIO220 and simple heatsink.
Some SMDs with due care.
An "off the shelf" or self built switching regulator allows lower dissipation.

Yoi could PWM a FET to limit effectoive voltage  / control current. Not hard but a hardware solution easier to ensure the safety of under all conditions.

> 1 X dc pump (5V, 300mA, on / off)

1 I/O bit.
Similar to 3V motor above.

> 2 X servo (5V, 100mA each, speed, direction, angle)

L298 will handle bi-directional drive.
Tacho feedback )(see below) allows speed and position control.

The fun begins.
It is not certain what you mean by speed/direction/angle without more detail as an standalone servo motor cannot have all 3 of these variables at once.
eg you can control speed - but angle has no meaning in isolation.
You can control the angle that the motor "points" when stationary but it then has no speed (or direction).
You can control the speed of two motors and the angle between them - which MAY be what you mean, but probably not.

A servo will take typically 3 bits to control. (Less with logic-magic).
You can control a single servo with 2 I/O bits and an H bridge as above.
You can determine speed with 1 bit and an optical or hall or ... sensor.
Or you can use a tachogenerator (not very hard) and mesure speed with an ADC input.

**OR**

Stepper motors would allow speed direction and position control. Position feedback could be via a home position sensor as long as the motor does not "slip" under drive load. For absolute closed loop position control some form of position feedback would be needed  = gray code disk, linear position inductive feedback, GMR sensor etc.

Overall, a stepper motor is easier when it works but harder to be sure that it is working.

---

Total

4    2 x Gear motors
1    12V motor
1     5V motor
1     3V motor
6     2 x servo motors

13 I/O bits total

**Port extending:**

If wanted you can latch some bits into external latches to reduce i/O pin use.
Parallel latches take N+1 bits. 5 for 4 bits, 9 for 8 bits
Serial latches take 1 or 2 or 3 bits depending on hardware magic for any number of serial bits.

Easiest is to latch on/off bits and to drive PWM directly from a pin.

Comment: Actually it's not ten. I have to operate two gear motors (12v each), one high rpm dc motor (again 12v), two servo motors, a 3-6V pump, few drivers and sensors. The specifications are not given on the website.

Comment: @AbhishekDaberao You are not helping yourself. If you want good answers (which we can give you if we know enough) then **YOU** need to tell us what you do know IN YOUR QUESTION. eg Gear motors draw about xxA at 12V. They are [on/off only | variable speed by varying voltage] and [monodirectional | need to be reversed by reversing voltage]. etc. WHAT website are the specs not given on? If YOU are going to hope to control thse you MUST know data re current, on off or variable, direction etc., HELP US HELP YOU !!!!

Comment: @AbhishekDaberao See added motor control information.

Comment: thanks, it solves my problem

Answer (score -1):

No, With motors it's not just voltage its also current. V*I=P so its the combined power output of an ardunio uno vs the power required to drive the motors. You'll need a separate power system or driver to be able to drive 10 motors.

Of course that depends on your motors I'm assuming no as you didnt spec your motors. But as an example lets say you have a 5V 150mA motor = 0.75W and 10 motors makes the power required 7.5W to drive all motors at at full, dont know off hand but I dont think an arduino can pump out 7.5W

Do your design for full power and if you dont use full power great, but if you design for say half power then you might hit problems when you start to load the motor.

***************EDITED*****************

Answer your question HELL NO you cant do this with an arduino uno, max power output is 5W your looking for 20W.

So while you cannot run your full system from an arduino uno you could use it as the controller.

You'll need a power supply of some kind something with 12V as thats your highest needed voltage the 12V can supply all your motors but your still talking a good bit of current so a battery that will be useful and last long enough is going to be expensive. then connect your motors via relays or FETs to this power supply and use the arduino as a controller.

Comment: I have updated details in question. Please review.